# How to vectorize 2D array using neon intrinsics

Tags: c, embedded, raspberry-pi3, neon, armv8

I am trying to add 50 to every element of a 2D array using neon intrinsic, here is my code, Is there any better way of doing it or optimizing it?

```
void fun(int height,int width,unsigned char array2D[][width],unsigned char *output){
uint8x16_t va,vb,res;
vb=vdupq_n_u8((unsigned char)50);
unsigned char *arr;
arr=&array2D[0][0]; //input array
//j=0;
int size=height*width;
for (i=0;i<size;i+=16)
{
    va=vld1q_u8(arr+i);
    res=vaddq_u8(va,vb);
    vst1q_u8(output+i,res);
}
 }
```

Comment: There are tons of improvments possible. Why don't you try to read the disassembly? I suggest studying computer architecture before digging into SIMD. (dependency, latency, etc)

Comment: not much can  be further improved. The problem is *memory bound* anyway. Maybe processing 4 vectors rather than 1 to handle the whole cache line at once (may give 10-20% speedup). Consider using OpenMP, add `#pragma omp parallel for` before `for` loop and `-fopenmp` to the compiler cmdline

Comment: Don't forget tail code to cope if you don't know that height*width is a multiple of 16

Answer (score 0):

As @tstanisl said, the operation is memory bound thus not much can be further improved. There are some possible ways worth a try though, like:

1. Unroll the loop with larger factor, processing as much vectors rather than 1 until register spilling occurred.
2. Using OpenMP to parallelize the loop if you have more CPU cores available.
3. Using `pld` to prefetch the input array(`__builtin_prefetch()` in intrinsic), and choose an suitable prefetch offset carefully and empirically.
4. Remember to turn on compiler option `-mcpu=cortex-xx` if you exactly knows that your compile target is fixed.